# DSP.js Fails in Most Browsers

Tags: javascript, signal-processing

The official examples for DSP.js work in Internet Explorer 11. However, the code fails to execute in the following browsers:

Chrome 67

Edge, the latest Windows 10 Update

Firefox 60

What can be done to solve this problem?